# How does Azure Policy get triggered?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to understand how Azure triggers my [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-policy/azure-policy-introduction) definition to scan and validate my target scope in Azure subscription. Understanding that with policy template, saying that I can compose a policy to check [whether a storage has encryption enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-policy/scripts/ensure-store-file-enc) and got to see **compliance state** and **non-compliance resources** after assigning the policy template.

[image]

What I realize is that after assigning my policy template around 5-10 minutes, I see the compliance check result.

When does my policy get triggered? Is it immediately after I assign my policy to a target scope? Or it needs an external job to execute?

Comment: so whats the question? or rather, what kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: @4c74356b41 thank you for your reply. The question is when a policy gets triggered. Is it immediately triggered after I assign my policy? Updated my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

After each assignment change Azure-Policy scans your policy assignment scope and stores the results. It depends on the size of your scope but it's safe to assume there is at least a 15 min delay.